# Call a function from within pdfMake in Ionic2?

Tags: ionic2, pdfmake

I have the following pdfMake code block in my ionic app:

```
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getBase64(function (encodedString) {
    pdfEncoded = encodedString;
    console.log(pdfEncoded);
    this.sendValue(pdfEncoded);
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> Cannot read property 'sendValue' of undefined.

What do I need to do to call the `sendValue()` function? I am able to `console.log` the value of `pdfEncoded` but unable to pass the value to a function. Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thank you,
A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason of the error maybe because the keyword 'this' might be undefined inside your function(block). Check for that and see if the error is because of that and if it is try this :

```
let $this = this
```

And then inside your function use it as:

```
$this.sendValue(pdfEncoded);
```